# SharePoint Online remove Remote Event Receivers from subwebs

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, remote-event-receiver

I am trying to develop an add-in for SharePoint Online that ensures all document libraries created get my company's base content type and the standard document content type gets removed.

I have the ListAdded remote event receiver working to do this task. I also have a WebProvisioned event receiver that will attach the listAdded event receiver to new sub-sites.

This now kinda works, however when the add-in gets removed it only removes the event receivers from the top level site and the event receivers in sub-sites get orphaned and can't be deleted. How can I loop through the sub-sites in the appuninstalling event?

I'd like to avoid having to install the add-in to every subsite.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured my problem out. I needed to be adding the remote event receiver at the site collection level and not the web level, which I didn't think was possible with CSOM.

So I needed using [this PNP example solution](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceiversBasedModifications) as a base, I needed to change `cc.Web.EventReceivers` to `cc.Site.EventReceivers` and also make sure the Addin had the correct access to the site collection.